# Retrofit, Volley and HttpURLConnection different reponse

Tags: android, android-volley, retrofit2, httpurlconnection

Making a simple request to the server giving me different response data. `Volley` and `HttpURLConnection` is giving me same response which I expected, however, when I request using retrofit its giving me totally different data.

Please bear in mind that it happens only when I use our **WIFI** and only in Mobile application. When I use browser and make same request I get expected data.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val alarmManger = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val intent = Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0)
        alarmManger.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                60 * 1000, pendingIntent)


        Thread {
            var conn = URL("$BASE_URL/home").openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            var inputStream = conn.inputStream

            val br = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
            var sB = StringBuilder()

            var line = br.readLine();
            if (line != null) {
                sB.append(line)
            }
            print(sB.toString())

        }.start()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build()
        val service = retrofit.create(GitHubService::class.java)
        service.listRepos().enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>?, t: Throwable?) {
                println(t)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>?, response: Response<ResponseBody>?) {
                println(response?.body())
            }

        })

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, BASE_URL + "/home",
                com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String> { response ->

                    println(response)
                },
                com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener { })
        queue.add(stringRequest)

    }


}



val BASE_URL = "myserviceurl";


interface GitHubService {
    @GET("home")
    fun listRepos(): Call<ResponseBody>
}
```

Comment: How different? What's the expected output? What's the actual output? Perhaps you wanted `response?.body()?.string()`?

Comment: Lets say I have two API endpoints api1 and api2 with  Json string response json1 and json2 respectively. When I use retrofit and make api1 request i get json 2 response. However when I use Volley or HttpURLConnection to make api1 request I get json1 as expected. Please note that the response from retrofit is not from cache. First I though it might be server issue, but when I make request using browser, HttpURLConnection or even volley I get json1 from api1 but from retrofit i get json2 from api1. If I used VPN or mobile network its working as expected.

Comment: Please noted that eventhough I have printed reponse body in code, I am debugging for response string